# Is there an easy way to add jars on surefire-plugin test classpath 

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

there is this property additionalClasspathElements but unfortunately it doesn't process directories with jars

this problem is really hard to deal with ... the only way that occurs to me is to create a mojo that prepares the classpath, but I don't know what would follow

creating a list of  175 jars in my pom definition would look funny.It would be 525 lines  within additionalClasspathElements

I need to boot up a huge project, that is not using maven. Declaring them would be almost impossible because of version compatibility of 175 libs. Imho loading them directly from the project's classpath is the only way

Comment: Can you use * to capture all the jars?

Comment: It actually doesn't work, I'm trying to debug it, the remote eclipse debugger connects to it, but it doesn't stop on the breakpoint in AbstractSurefireMojo ... Also there is no way to see the classpath in eclipse (when started in console) and linux $ps tool shows 2 maven processes, but they don't have the resulting -classpath ... the surefire plugin is really over-complicated

Comment: Omg, that surefire-plugin is totally undebuggable ... classloading/multithreaded hell

Comment: Nice, [a bug](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-860) open for three years. A lively project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, use wildcards for making classpath :

```
<additionalClasspathElements>
    <additionalClasspathElement>
        /path/to/lib/*.jar
    </additionalClasspathElement>
</additionalClasspathElements>
```

You have to use these properties :

```
<useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>  
<useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
```

Because, take a look at ForkConfiguration.java :

```
if ( useManifestOnlyJar )
{
    File jarFile;
    try
    {
        jarFile = createJar( classPath );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        throw new SurefireBooterForkException( "Error creating archive file", e );
    }

    cli.createArg().setValue( "-jar" );

    cli.createArg().setValue( jarFile.getAbsolutePath() );
}
else
{
    cli.addEnvironment( "CLASSPATH", StringUtils.join( classPath.iterator(), File.pathSeparator ) );

    final String forkedBooter = ForkedBooter.class.getName();

    cli.createArg().setValue( shadefire ? new Relocator().relocate( forkedBooter ) : forkedBooter );
}
```

You want the classpath to get concatenated and appended to the CLI, not manifest-only JAR...

This should work for simple dependencies. But if you want to boot up something big, something that using classloader, I would recommend what bmargulies does. Cause you would fight that hard imho :-) **[See here why](http://marksweep.blogspot.com/2011/11/booting-up-ant-project-when-testing.html)**.

For inspiration, [I wrote a dependency installer](http://marksweep.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-use-liferay-third-party.html) that installs jars into local maven repository and generates pom definition with all those dependencies so that you can use itself as a dependency (which put all its dependencies on classpath - transitive dependencies)... Best way to go imho. It is quite a generic Mojo, it doesn't necessary have to be used on Liferay. You just have to play with it a little.

Comment: Confirmed to work with surefire 2.18.1, but didn't with 2.14.1.

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script that iterates over all those jars, calling mvn install:install-file with a fabricated groupId, artifactId, and version.

Make the shell script write out XML for Maven `<dependency/>` elements for all of them, with `<scope>test</scope>`.

Insert resulting blob of XML into POM.

Stand back.

Comment: I'm contributing to the software on daily basis, the build/deploy process of the software that is overly complicated anyhow, would get even more complex by installing the dependencies after each build...just for running the test... I will figure out how to debug surefire plugin and submit a fix for additionalClasspathElement to accept wildcards

Comment: This might seem like a straightforward way to go, but it is actually wrong thing to do imho. I did this a year ago with an Ant script. Installing dummy artifacts with no metadata just because surefire plugin has this drawback

Comment: Look, surefire is *part of maven*. It's not reasonable to expect it to have all sorts of crocks in it to aid completely non-maven use cases. You could script my procedure in ant and it could be completely automated.